# VBA - how to choose a column containing a specific cell and name it output column?

Tags: excel, vba

There is a cell in another worksheet whose value ranges from 1 to 100, I have defined its name as "SpanLength" in the name manager. In the worksheet I am now concerned with, I want to find the cell which contains the same value as "SpanLength", that is, a value from 1 to 100, within the range I have defined as "FindSpanLength". Then I want to call the column that this cell is within "outputcolumn" so that I can use this column further in the script. How can I do this?

The line of code before End Sub causes the error message 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'

I am a VBA novice and no doubt my code is fraught with errors, so would appreciate any help I can get. I have already scoured google for answers but haven't found any specific enough for me to understand.

```
Sub OutputMaximums()

Dim spanlengthcell As Range
Set spanlengthcell = Range("FindSpanLength").Find("SpanLength")
Range("spanlengthcell").Column(1) = outputcolumn 

End Sub
```

New Code, with error message 1004 (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed):

```
Sub OutputMaximums()

Dim spanlengthcell As Range, outputcolumn As Long
Set spanlengthcell = OUTPUT.Range("FindSpanLength").Find(Range("SpanLength").Value)
If Not spanlengthcell Is Nothing Then
outputcolumn = spanlengthcell.Column
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "whose name I have assigned as "SpanLength" " - do you mean the cell contains that text or you have named the cell as that?

Comment: There is a cell in another worksheet whose value ranges from 1 to 100, I have defined its name as "SpanLength" in the name manager. In the worksheet I am now concerned with, I want to find the cell which contains the same value as "SpanLength", that is, a value from 1 to 100, within the range I have defined as "FindSpanLength"

Comment: Perhaps you could add that to your question as it's a useful description.

Comment: So you have named a cell (or maybe a range) as `SpanLength`. You don't need to `set` this in your UDF as excel already knows what this is now. It is available in `VBA` just as it is in an excel sheet. You can reference it just as been suggested by simple-solution

Comment: thanks! I will edit my description now.

Comment: Just get rid of "OUTPUT."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a value to a variable, the variable is on the left hand side of the equals sign.

When using `Find` always check first that your search term is found before trying to access its properties to avoid subsequent errors.

It is also advisable to specify a number of `Find` parameters as they may have unexpected settings from when last used on a worksheet.

```
Sub OutputMaximums()

Dim spanlengthcell As Range, outputcolumn As Long

Set spanlengthcell = Range("FindSpanLength").Find(Range("SpanLength").Value)
If Not spanlengthcell Is Nothing Then
    outputcolumn = spanlengthcell.Column
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, however with my new code, error message 1004 appears (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed). I have written my new code in the description at the top of this page ^

Comment: Have you tried my code as posted? Are your ranges scoped to the workbook or a specific sheet?

Comment: I've tried your code and it makes sense to me but comes up with the 1004 error. My ranges are all scoped to the whole workbook

Comment: In that case you don't need any sheet references. I can't replicate your error with my code as posted above. Which line errors?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong - this workbook had a duplicated sheet which was contained the same named range. Thanks for your tip on the range scopes, I wouldn't have got it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, the code seems to run fine and I'm going to incorporate it into my other script now!

Comment: Glad we got there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ShowNamedRange()

'The named Range "SpanLenght" must be on the Sheet "SheetWithNamedRange"!

Debug.Print Sheet("SheetWithNamedRange").Range("SpanLength").Address
Debug.Print Sheet("SheetWithNamedRange").Range("SpanLength").Column

End Sub
```

and after reading the question again:

```
Sub SearchRange()
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = Sheets("SheetWithNamedRange").Range("SpanLength").Value
    Set rngSearch = Sheets("SheetWithFINDRange").Range("FindSpanLength")
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(strSearch)

    If Not (rngFound Is Nothing) Then _
       MsgBox "Found in column " & rngFound.Column & _
         " on the sheet """ & rngFound.Parent.Name & """!"
End Sub
```

Comment: OP has now clarified the question and is looking for the cell's value in another range.

Comment: Try and avoid using things like `ActiveSheet`. It's fraught with danger as at any given point an active sheet might not be the sheet you want to reference

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I'll give this code a go to see if it works with my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim ColumnNo As Long

    strSearch = "Bingo"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngSearch = .UsedRange

        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(strSearch)

        If rngFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox strSearch & " does not excist in range."
        Else
            ColumnNo = rngFound.Column

            MsgBox "Text appears in column " & ColumnNo & "."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I'll give this code a go now and see if it works alongside my code.